# Error Class "Laravel\Fortify\Features" not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-fortify

I have ecommerce laravel application.

```
Laravel Framework 8.83.8
PHP v8.0.1
```

I have done

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:cache
```

I deployed it on Cloudways (Digital Ocean) via Git.
but when I try to run my website it shows error

```
Error Class "Laravel\Fortify\Features" not found
```

[Error image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loT9T.png)

I have used fortify features in *fortify.php*

```
use Laravel\Fortify\Features;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
```

```
 'features' => [
        Features::registration(),
        Features::resetPasswords(),
        Features::emailVerification(),
        Features::updateProfileInformation(),
        Features::updatePasswords(),
        Features::twoFactorAuthentication([
            'confirmPassword' => true,
        ]),
    ],
```

When I comment out all Fortify features then it shows another error Jetstream features not found.

I can't understand where is the problem.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

To start using fortify you need first ,install Fortify using the Composer package manager

```
composer require laravel/fortify
```

then you need to, publish Fortify's resources using the vendor:publish command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Fortify\FortifyServiceProvider"
```

then  you should migrate your DB

```
php artisan migrate
```

for more info please check [Laravel Fortify Installation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/fortify#installation)

Comment: I have already do that early when i was developing this project. this work fine in local environment but when i deploy this project on Server (Cloudways) then it gives this error.

Comment: This project is ready for production does installing Fortify again will effect it?